# grade: mutual exclusion for independent dependencies

Tags: gradle

I've got a somewhat esoteric situation with a grade project I'm working on. I've got two totally independent projects (call them A and B). I want to set up the gradle configuration of project A so that if it's included in some other library/application C, the build will fail if C also has a dependency on project B.

So for example, if I have a project C that looks like either this:

```
dependencies {
   implementation("A")
}
```

or this

```
dependencies {
   implementation("B")
}
```

project C would build fine. But if project C would look like this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation("A")
  implementation("B")
}
```

it would fail to build.

A couple constraints on the problem that makes it a little more challenging:

- For reasons too complicated to dig into here, project C can't really know about this mutual exclusion.
- The code inside projects A & B don't know about each other.

Does grade have a feature that can support what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you may try:

**1. Declare that project A provides the same capability as project B (assuming you have access to update project A)**

```
# A/build.gradle

configurations {
    apiElements {
        outgoing {
            // format: groupId:name:version

            // default capability for project A
            capability("gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A:1.0.0")

            // new capability which is the same as default capability in project B
            capability("gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0")
        }
    }
}
```

So, when you publish artifact for project A, gradle will publish module metadata alongside the normal descriptor for a given repository (Maven or Ivy). That module metadata includes capabilities set above.

In project C if you try to use both dependencies A and B as follows:

```
# C/build.gradle

dependencies {
    implementation 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0'
    implementation 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A:1.0.0'
}
```

It should fail because both dependencies provide the same capability `gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0` and gradle doesn't allow this:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':C:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :C
      > Module 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B' has been rejected:
           Cannot select module with conflict on capability 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0' also provided by [gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A:1.0.0(apiElements)]
   > Could not resolve gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :C
      > Module 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A' has been rejected:
           Cannot select module with conflict on capability 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0' also provided by [gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0(apiElements)]
```

Note: project B may have a different version which is also fine and should work.

**2. Set a capability rule in project C (assuming you have access to update project C)**

```
# C/build.gradle

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class ABCapability implements ComponentMetadataRule {
    final static Set<String> AB_MODULES = ["A", "B"] as Set<String>

    void execute(ComponentMetadataContext context) {
        context.details.with {
            if (AB_MODULES.contains(id.name)) {
                allVariants {
                    it.withCapabilities {
                        // Declare that both A and B provide the same capability
                        it.addCapability("AB", "AB", id.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    components.all(ABCapability)

    implementation 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0'
    implementation 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A:1.0.0'
}
```

This is very similar logic which relies on using the same capability for both projects A and B. The failure in this case looks as follows:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':C:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :C
      > Module 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B' has been rejected:
           Cannot select module with conflict on capability 'AB:AB:1.0.0' also provided by [gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A:1.0.0(apiElements)]
   > Could not resolve gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :C
      > Module 'gradle.mutual.exclusion.a:A' has been rejected:
           Cannot select module with conflict on capability 'AB:AB:1.0.0' also provided by [gradle.mutual.exclusion.b:B:1.0.0(apiElements)]
```